# Use SQL functions like substr(X, Y, Z) in SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, sql-function

I could not figure out how to use SQLite's functions like [substr(X, Y, Z)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) with SQLAlchemy's query expression syntax. I am aware that I could use raw queries, but that would make it more difficult to reuse my where clauses. Here is my use case:

I have a table (or model class) of file headers which I query to identify and list files of certain types.

```
class Blob(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'blob'

    _id = Column('_id', INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    size = Column('size', INTEGER)
    hash = Column('hash', TEXT)
    header = Column('header', BLOB)
    meta = Column('meta', BLOB)
```

For example, to identify Exif images, I can use this raw query:

```
select * from blob where substr(header,7,4) = X'45786966'
```

`X'45786966'` is simply the SQLite `BLOB` literal for the string `Exif` encoded in ASCII. In reality, the where clauses are more complex and I would like to re-use them as filter conditions for joins, approximately like this:

```
# define once at module level
exif_conditions = [functions.substr(Blob.header, 7, 4) == b'Exif']

# reuse for arbitrary queries
session.query(Blob.hash).filter(*exif_conditions)
session.query(...).join(...).options(...).filter(condition, *exif_conditions)
```

Is there a way to achieve this with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok. This was way too simple.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
exif_conditions = [func.substr(Blob.header, 7, 4) == b'Exif']
```